# Bulk Uploading Images using Excel sheet Data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, oracle

I have a Excel sheet which contains data regarding the Physical file path of Images and I want to import this excel sheet and upload images(path in excel sheet) mentioned in that excel sheet in C#.net

I have done up to getting the data of excel sheet in to data table
but i am not able to upload the images of the path mentioned in the Excel to server

Please help me

Manoj

Comment: In what way are you "not able to upload the images of the path"?  Are you trying something and it's failing?  Or do you not know how to do this?  But the most important question is, *what directories do the loaded paths point to?* We can load files into Oracle databases, but only from directories which are visible to the database (which usually means on the same physical server as the database).

Comment: Also, you have tagged your question with both [oracle] and [sql-server]: do you really want solutions for both databases?